# How to compose a Cross-Domain JSON/Ajax call to a simple web service

Tags: jquery

I have a web service with this form:

```
http://<remote_domain_ip>/api/v1/search/?query=the_query
```

Which results a JSON document in response.

How do I create/compose a JQuery JSON/ajax call so I can get the response back?

Reponse is in form:

```
{
"status_code":200,
"status_txt":"OK",
"field1":"abc",
"field2":"some_text"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are say on domain `a.com` and your web service is also located at the same place, then you can simply do it this way:

```
$.ajax('path-to-your-service/WebMethodName', data, function(r){
    // Success callback, you have your answer in r.d object
}, function(e){
    // Error callback
});
```

However, if you are on say `b.com` and the web service is located on `a.com`, then you are limited by a concept called [Same-Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In other words, you can't use AJAX calls (or XMLHttpRequest) to fetch data from that web service, unless you follow certain rules. One is to use **[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)** HTTP Header field, which has some cross-browser issues. Another way could be to use [JSONP](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/), which requires the server to support it.

To use JSONP, you should use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method, and provide a callback query string key alongside your parameters sent via HTTP GET.

```
$.getJSON('path-to-your-service?x=some&y=thing?callback?', function(r){
    // Success callback. Your JSON object would be the r parameter
});
```

I recommend that you use JSONP, if you are the creator of the web service, and if you use .NET framework, I also recommend that you simply use a **Generic Handler** instead of a web service, since we had many problems configuring web service. However, in your server code, you should check the incoming GET request for a query string key called **callback**, and if it exists, you should wrap your returning JSON inside a function this way:

```
callback({
   a: a1,
   b: b1,
   c: c1
});
```

Understanding JSONP (the concept and the way it occurs) is very crucial. Without a deep understanding, your future maintenance would be a huge burden. I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp) question.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, assuming  is not the same domain you're on. If you have access to  remote_domain_ip, or can get them to host a file for you, you can use [EasyXDM](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=easyxdm&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://easyxdm.net/&ei=RG25TpPxCurC2wXO58CzBw&usg=AFQjCNEFqdBtQeUZP60yoYsabYJJOzOZgQ). There are similar work-around tools involving Flash you can try. Otherwise, you'll need to perform the request on the back end.